# CSS: fly-in menu on a centred site

Tags: css, menu

Designers that don't need to write code.... sigh.

Before I go back and tell him it's not possible, I thought I'd canvas the stackoverflow  brain.

A centred website, with a slide-in menu. My understanding is that slide-in menus generally work by hiding the menu off the left side of the viewport. i.e. only valid on a left anchored site.

I have a site that does it by expanding the side menu (i.e. it can sit invisible with a width:0 but not sliding in.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Mocking it up in code at the moment is not as useful as someone having a generalised idea of how it might be done. This isn't really a debugging question so much as a "is it possible?" question. @Paulie_D Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: "Is it possible" questions are off-topic for SO. The idea is, you try it, show us what didn't work and we help you with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it written, the menu is fixed to the left. But you can modify the code to:

1. wrap the menu and button into a centered `div` with `overflow:hidden`
2. position the menu `nav` relatively and instead of manipulating `left` property of the menu, use `margin-left`
3. `position:fixed` the button's container `div` to `top:0` and `right` to the width of the button
4. don't toggle the body.

Too much code to post, so here's your updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/xofafoba/1/**

Answer (score 1):

Give the centered container a property of `overflow:hidden;` which will hide the side-menu till it's inside the centered container. From what I understood by the question, this should solve it.